# How to check if a directory exists in Firebase Storage?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

### My setup

- Unity : 2019.1.6f1
- Firebase Version : 6.2.0
- Firebase Product : Storage

---

Let's say there is directory "Text" & its immediate parent is the root directory.

That directory (from my tests) will only appear if there is/are any files within that directory. That directory will delete itself if there aren't any files in that directory.

### Request

Thank you

Now is there a way to know if such a directory existing using Unity's firebase API?

I wish I could have provided some sample, I am unable to find any samples pointing to directory instead of a file.

---

This is not a DUPLICATE question as certain API calls are present/absent in other platforms within Firebase.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Come on frank, this isn't a duplicate question when you consider https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#list 

There isn't such in Unity docs hence wonder if there might be any other solution.

Comment: The Firebase APIs are quite consistent across platforms. If something doesn't exist on one platform, it is very unlikely it exists on another platform. The only exception there may be for new functionality, which typically comes out for iOS, Android, and Web first, with other platforms trailing. But the ability to check for a folder isn't present in any of those platforms either.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for replying. Then the answer for Unity is that it is trailing behind iOS, Android & Web. So how can the question be a duplicate?  Esp. when I see this API call? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#list

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no such thing as a "folder" in Cloud Storage.  There are just paths to objects that look like folders, and the Firebase console lets you navigate as if there are folders, but no folders actually exist.  You'll notice that if you delete a file out of a "folder", then entire folder goes away from the console (because it never existed).

When you create a file, you don't have to create any of the parent "folders".  Just identify the path of the file, and it will all exist when you write that file.

Comment: Well, thats what I initially though until I found this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#list

Hence wanted to know if there 'might' some similar solution for Unity + Firebase.

Comment: All the list API is doing is matching files that have the same prefix, which also happens to look like a folder.